# Why is Hagrid's face obscured in the memory recollection in Tom Riddle's Diary?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, the movie, the diary of Riddle pulls Harry in to view a memory. Riddle confronts Hagrid about Aragog and accuses him of causing the death of the student.

In the movie portrayal, however, Hagrid's face stays in shadow the entire time. Why is that? You still know it's him, due to his size and voice, and since Riddle outright says it.

Did the producers want to make the memory seem like a fake memory? According to the books, it was a real, unaltered, and unfabricated memory (from what I remember, at least).

Or perhaps they didn't want to find a similar actor? One that looked younger but whose face was still similar to Robbie Coltrane, for simply a 30-second clip of the movie.

As it was, it almost looks like they put in a different actor and used voiceover for the lines. It feels fake watching that scene, so I thought I'd ask to see if there was more of a reason for the portrayal shown in the movie.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## It probably wasn’t to show the memory as fake.

The first reference to memories looking obscured because they were tampered with was in “Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince”, which was published in 2005.

The movie for “Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets” was released in 2002, so the movie came out years before the book references to false memories looking obscured was published. JKR probably hadn’t even thought of it yet.

## It was most likely to obscure the fact that they used another actor.

Robbie Coltrane, the actor who played Hagrid, was *not* the one playing young Hagrid in the memory scene. Instead, it was [Martin Bayfield](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0062992/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t70), who also was Hagrid’s body double, playing young Hagrid in that scene. It’s likely they chose to obscure his face to make the fact that they used a different actor less noticeable.

Finding an actor as large as Hagrid, who also resembles him enough to plausibly be a younger version of him, would be quite a difficult task. It’s likely they figured using his stunt double, who had a similar build, and obscuring his face would be better than looking for a new actor to play young Hagrid in that memory scene.

Comment: Would they really need an actor *as large*?

Comment: no - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09-LcgpPHO8 - Coltrane is tall but not 'Hagrid" tall